# buildnumber-maven-plugin Placing Jar in Branch Folder

Tags: java, maven, svn, buildnumber-maven-plugin

I'd like to create jar files like `target/myproject-mytag.jar`, but when I run maven, I end up with `target/myproject-tags/mytag/myproject.jar`. How can I get a jar file named `myproject-mytag.jar`?

Here's the important snippets from my pom:

```xml
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${scmBranch}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>create</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I'm not sure if it matters, but this is a child in a multi-module maven project stored in SVN.

Thanks,
David

Comment: I should add - it does exactly what I'm looking for if I have the trunk checked out. But, when I check a tag out, I get the above results with the folder hierarchy that I didn't ask for.

Comment: I'd be open to running another plugin following buildnumber (maybe assembly?) if it could parse the folder structure and copy/move the jar to my preferred destination. If anyone knows how to do that too, I'd happily accept it.